# How to create prototype for collection using different entries types

Tags: php, forms, symfony, collections, php-8

I am trying to create a form tu manage sliders. I this form, I need to add slides. Each slide can be a video or an image.

To do that, I created a parent class which has communs attributes (position, active ...) and two others classes with specifics attributes.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Slider;

use App\Repository\Slider\SlideRepository;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\InheritanceType('JOINED')]
#[ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name: 'slide_type', type: Types::STRING)]
#[ORM\DiscriminatorMap([
    'image' => Image::class,
    'video' => Video::class
])]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: SlideRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'tmp_slide')]
class Slide
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer', nullable: true)]
    private ?int $position;

    // getters and setters
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Slider;

use App\Repository\Slider\VideoRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: VideoRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'tmp_slide_video')]
class Video extends Slide
{
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private string $source;
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Slider;

use App\Repository\Slider\ImageRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ImageRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'tmp_slide_image')]
class Image extends Slide
{
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private string $meta_alt;
}
```

So I created the form and for the slide collection, I use form events to set the good form following [the doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)

```php
$form->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
                /** @var Slide $slide */
                $slide = $event->getData();
                $form = $event->getForm();

                if ($slide) {

                    switch (get_class($slide)) {
                        case Video::class:
                            $form->add('source', TextType::class);
                        break;
                        case Image::class:
                            $form->add('meta_alt', TextType::class);
                        break;
                        default:
                            throw new \Exception('Undefined slide type');
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
```

That perfectly works for updating but like this I do not found the way to generate the prototype to add a slide with the choice of image or video.

So the question is : How to create two different prototypes for those two types of slide ?

I really hope you will understand the problem
Thank you for help

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand your question. Can you you elaborate use case, framework, screenshot of working and non working page.